# Resetting next sequence ID on SERIAL column

Tags: informix, autonumber

After committing a row with a SERIAL (autonumber) column, the row is deleted, but when another row is added, the deleted row's sequence ID is not reused.

The only way I have found for reusing the deleted row's sequence ID is to ALTER the SERIAL column to an INTEGER, then change it back to a SERIAL.

Is there an easier quicker way for accomplishing the resetting of the next sequence ID so that there are no gaps in the sequence?

NOTE: This is a single-user application, so no worries about multiple users simultaneously inserting rows.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a particularly easy way to do that.  You can reset the number by inserting … hmmm, once upon a long time ago, there were bugs in this, and you're using ancient enough versions of the software that on occasions the bug might still be relevant, though all current versions of Informix products do not have the bug.

The safe technique is to insert: 2<sup>31</sup>-2 (note the minus 2; that's +2,147,483,646), then insert a row with 0 (to generate +2,147,483,647), then insert another row with 0 to trip the next sequence number back to 1.  That insert operation will fail if there's already a row with 1 in the system and you have a unique constraint on the SERIAL column.  You then need to insert the maximum value, or the value before the first gap that you want to fill (another failing insert).  However, note that after filling the gap, the inserted values will increase by one, bumping into any still existing rows and causing insertion failures (because you do have a unique constraint/index on each SERIAL column, don't you — and don't 'fess up if you do not have such indexes; just go and add them!).

If you have a more recent version of Informix, you can insert +2,147,483,647 and then a single row to wrap the value without running into trouble.  If you have an old version of Informix with the bug, then inserting +2,147,482,647 directly caused problems.  IIRC, the trouble was that you ended up with NULLs being generated, but it was long enough ago now (another millennium) that I'm not absolutely sure of that any more.

None of this is really easy, in case you hadn't noticed.

Generally speaking, it is unwise to fill the gaps; you're better off leaving them and not worrying about them, or inserting some sort of dummy record that says "this isn't really a record — but the serial value is otherwise missing so I'm here to show that we know about it and it isn't missing but isn't really used either".

Comment: hmm, your suggestions sound more complicated than what i'm currently doing, changing serial datatype to an integer, then back to serial. i'm also not trying to wraparound to ID=1. I have, for example: ID's 100, 101 and 102. then, a user deletes 102, and I want to reuse 102 when the next row is added. are you suggesting I not allow user to delete any rows?

Comment: .. BTW, this is SE 4.10.DC1

Comment: I'm suggesting that you shouldn't worry about 102 going missing.

Comment: I won't, but the auditors will. if the row is deleted, there's no way of adding a reason as to why it was deleted, just a gap in the sequence.

Comment: .. there are certain cases when its best not to use SERIAL datatype, and instead use INTEGER so you can custom manage sequences. my scenario looks like a candidate for this.

Comment: The add a marker to indicate that the row is logically deleted, and don't allow people to physically delete the record.  Let them logically delete it, and you can add reasons why somewhere too (possibly in a separate table of logical deletion information for this table, which can record who and when as well as why).